How to align xarray dimensions without performing calculation?
I have 2 DataArrays with partially overlapping dimensions. If I perform any calculation the dimensions of the result are auto aligned according to the exact matches between the overlapping dimensions.
How can I achieve the same result without performing the redundant calculation below:y_da.y * x_da.x/x_da.x?
I tried: align, broadcast, merge methods without any success...
import xarray as xr
import pandas as pd

x_da = pd.DataFrame({
    'reporting_date': pd.to_datetime([
        '2024-01-01','2024-02-01','2024-03-01',
        '2024-01-01','2024-02-01','2024-03-01',
        '2024-01-01','2024-02-01','2024-03-01',
    ]),
    'user': [
        'A','A','A',
        'B','B','B',
        'C','C','C',
    ],
    'rating': [
        1,1,1,
        1,2,3,
        3,2,1
    ],
    'x': [
        10,20,30,
        20,30,40,
        30,40,50
    ]
})

y_da = pd.DataFrame({
    'rating': [
        1,1,1,1,1,1,
        2,2,2,2,2,2,
        3,3,3,3,3,3
    ],
    'horizon': [
        1,2,3,4,5,6,
        1,2,3,4,5,6,
        1,2,3,4,5,6
    ],
    'y': [
        0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,
        0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,
        0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,
    ]
})

x_da = x_da.set_index(['user','reporting_date','rating']).to_xarray()
y_da = y_da.set_index(['rating','horizon']).to_xarray()


ds = x_da.assign(y=y_da.y * x_da.x/x_da.x)


display(ds.sel({'user':'A'}).y)



For one thing, ds = x_da.assign(y = y_da.y + xr.zeros_like(x_da)) does a faster redundant calculation

You tried aligning the datasets along the "rating" dimension ?

To align xarray dimensions without performing a calculation, you can use the xr.align() method, which aligns the dimensions of two or more DataArrays or Datasets. This method is flexible and allows you to adjust how dimensions are aligned using the join argument:
join='outer': includes all indexes
join='inner': includes only the common indexes
join='left' or join='right': aligns based on the first or second array

This alignment ensures the arrays are ready for subsequent operations but does not perform any calculations.
Additionally, you could also use broadcast_like if you want one DataArray to match the dimensions of another without triggering any operations.
Example:
array1_aligned, array2_aligned = xr.align(array1, array2, join="outer")


try it on the provided example and you will see that it doesn't give the desired result
